# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null, does not send data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I have this sort code snippet:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id="submitform"}))

document.getElementById("submitform").submit();
```

and I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit'
> ```

Comment: You're missing *a lot* of details in your question.  But, in general, if the browser is telling you that something is `null` then it's `null`.  Regardless of any assumptions you've made.  You're going to have to diagnose this further.

Comment: Look ate the html you are generating - the `<form>` does not have an `id` attribute - you are adding a route value (hence `document.getElementById("submitform")` returns `undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't do what you think it does.  The overload for `BeginForm` that takes an object as its only parameter uses it for `RouteValues`, not attributes to be added.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.Object%29

You are setting the target of the form to be `http://foo/bar?id=submitform` instead of adding an `id` attribute, so there is no element with an `id` of `submitform` on your page.

Look here for an overload that takes `htmlAttributes` to set an ID, or just use `<form id="submitform">` instead.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx